# How to disable avahi-daemon in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: printing, services, 16.04, avahi

How to disable `avahi-daemon` in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS? I have tried

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'manual'>/etc/init/avahi-daemon.override"
```

but seems it does not work.

And how to disable `cups-browsed`? I have tried

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'manual'>/etc/init/cups-browsed.override"
```

but seems it does not work.

Comment: I hate ubuntu for breaking everything

Answer (score 9):

Since 16.04 is a systemd system, you need to do

```
sudo systemctl disable avahi-daemon.socket
sudo systemctl disable avahi-daemon.service
```

Also, the cups-browsed.service "Wants" avahi to start, so you'll either have to disable that, too, or comment out the line in `/lib/systemd/system/cups-browsed.service`:

```
Wants=avahi-daemon.service
```

Then you don't need to uninstall anything.

This won't take effect until reboot, but you can do

```
sudo systemctl stop avahi-daemon.socket
sudo systemctl stop avahi-daemon.service
```

If you want to stop it right away.

Comment: sudo systemctl disable avahi-daemon.socket /
sudo systemctl disable avahi-daemon.service - this doesn't work, after reboot avahi-daemon starts anyway.

Comment: True. It turns out cups-browsed.service wants to pull it in. I've udpated my answer and verified avahi no longer starts on reboot on my system.

Comment: I had to remove the `avahi-autoipd` package for this to take effect. Though the `avahi-daemon` was disabled and, in my case, uninstalled, ifup was still starting the `avahi-autoipd` service leading to my issues.

Answer (score 7):

After trying a couple of things, the one wich worked for me was

```
apt-get remove avahi-daemon
```

Comment: Lol. Probably what everyone wants to do. I saw that thing using CPU and just deleted it.

Comment: it's a dirty job, hopefully it will not came back again.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried

```
update-rc.d -f avahi-daemon remove  
echo manual > /etc/init/avahi-daemon.override
systemctl disable avahi-daemon
systemctl disable avahi-service
```

but still avahi-daemon came up after reboot.
So I ended up with
    `apt-get purge avahi-daemon`

which finally solved the problem for me.

Comment: liked the approach.