# Remove unwanted printers

Tags: 20.04, printing, libreoffice, cups-lpd

When I go to printers on localhost or cups, I only see two printers that I want to use...

When I go to settings printers or print dialog from like Libre Office I see bunch of network printers that I don't want to use...

Deleting them from Settings-Printers, does nothing, they show up again...

[image]

Ubuntu 20.04

Answer given here, does not help https://askubuntu.com/a/497769/513874

Also cups browsed is disabled

```
#systemctl status cups-browsed
● cups-browsed.service - Make remote CUPS printers available locally
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cups-browsed.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

Comment: [Stop 20.04 autoadding printers](https://7thzero.com/blog/how-to-stop-ubuntu-20-04-from-auto-adding-network-printers)

Comment: @24601 it does not work, cups-browsed is already disabled I will update my question.

Comment: Some users want nothing whatsoever to do with cups-browsed. Why leave it on the system? `apt purge cups-browsed` and report back.

Comment: @brian_p tried, printers are still here. I think it's something about gnome calling avahi all the time.

Comment: @AleksandarPavić it is, avahi will add every printer it sees every time. There are q's on au on how to disable avahi ;-)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1314634/how-do-i-disable-automatic-printer-discovery-in-ubuntu-20-10 or https://askubuntu.com/questions/205937/how-can-i-disable-avahi-daemon or https://askubuntu.com/questions/761292/how-to-disable-avahi-daemon-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts or https://askubuntu.com/questions/345132/should-i-disable-avahi-daemon

Answer (score 1):

- CUPS detects every printer on the network using avahi-daemon. List what it sees with `lpstat -l -e`.
- Entrues marked **permanent** are **print queues** set up either **manually** or **automatically** with cups-browsed. Localhost displays only permanent entries.
- The remaining entries **are not** print queues. They are simply printers **enumerated** by CUPS from what avahi-daemon tells it.
- Some apps on 20.04 (more on 21.04) can communicate with CUPS to enumerate the non-permanent printers. LibreOffice is one such app.
- **Only when an enumerated entry is printed to** is a print queue formed. The queue lasts for a minute and then disappears. It is a **temporary** queue.
- Therefore, `lpstat -l -e` shows potential (temporary) and permanent queue entries.
- Temporary queues are an important feature of the present and future **driverless printing** framework.
- Disabling or purging avahi-daemon removes the driverless printing benefits and all queues have to be permanent and set up with vendor drivers. Users doing this will run into big trouble in upcoming Ubuntus.
- There isn't any way as yet for apps or CUPS to filter enumerated printers.

Comment: Thanks @brian_p so it seems like Ubuntu needs new feature to filter those entries (mark some not to be shown). Or something like that... In my case I see like 25 printers...

Answer (score 0):

So the only way that I was able to disable unwanted printers is to block them via firewall.

Following steps are required:

1. List all printers via `lpstat -l -e`
2. Find their IP's via `avahi-browse --all -t -r`
3. Enable and install **ufw**
4. Disable individual printers by `ufw deny to printer_ip`